# How to differentiate between queued and running futures (and kill futures that have been running for too long)

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

When using futures on dask.distributed, is there a way to differentiate between `pending` futures that are currently being evaluated, and those that are still in the queue?

The reason is that I am submitting a large number of tasks (~8000) to a smaller set of workers (100), so not all tasks can be processed immediately. The tasks involve calling a third-party executable (*via* `subprocess.check_output`) which in some rare cases goes into an infinite loop.

Therefore, I would like to cancel futures to have been running for too long (using an arbitrary timeout). However there doesn't seem to be a way to tell whether a future has been in a `pending` state for a long time because computations take longer than usual, or simply because it had to wait for a worker to become available.

My setup involves a SGE cluster running a `dask-scheduler` and `dask-worker` job/job-array, respectively.
I tried setting a timeout directly in the submitted Python function, using `@timeout_decorator.timeout(60, use_signals=False)` from the [timeout_decorator package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/timeout-decorator), but got the following error:

```
"daemonic processes are not allowed to have children"
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can not determine if a task has started executing or not.  Generally we recommend putting this logic in the task itself as you have tried to do with your timeout decorator.

I recommend instead trying the `timeout=` keyword to `subprocess.check_outputs` itself.  I suspect that this will be simpler and have a higher chance of working smoothly.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I am running Python 2 where `subprocess` lacks the `timeout=` keyword, but I was able to get the same effect with the code in my answer below. That is an implementation-specific detail though, so I am marking this answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

For users running Python 2, the `timeout=` keyword is not available in `subprocess.check_output`.

I was able to get the desired effect by using `subprocess.Popen` instead, which returns immediately:

```py
import subprocess
import shlex  # useful to split up arguments for subprocess
import time

p = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split('/path/to/binary arg1 arg2'),
                     stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
for _ in range(60):  # wait for up to 60 seconds
    if p.poll() is not None:
        break  # process completed
    else:
        time.sleep(1.0)  # give it more time
if p.poll() is None:  # time is up, are we done?
    try:
        p.kill()
    except:
        raise
    raise RuntimeError('Binary failed to complete in time.')
```